# Adding a column with the same value when inserting multiple rows with Model::insert()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have an array of data extracted from a CSV file and insert the data in to the DB with:

```
HistoricData::insert($csv->content);
```

The array being inserted looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": "1619138160000",
    "open": "51917.16",
    "close": "51846.89",
    "high": "51919",
    "low": "51804.44"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "1619138100000",
    "open": "51954.86",
    "close": "51917.15",
    "high": "51954.86",
    "low": "51914.06"
  }]
```

However, I also want to add an extra column called "historic_data_group_id" and have it equal to 1 for every row being inserted.

Is there a way to do this without having to cycle through the array and adding that for every element before calling the model's insert method? In the real world application this array has many thousand elements and so I would prefer a more efficient way if possible.

Comment: Use the hack - if it can be apply. Add nullable column, and after insert csv - `UPDATE historic_data SET historic_data_group_id = {id} where historic_data_group_id IS NULL`. Use transaction for consistent and lock table on that period.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map()`

```
$csvContent = array_map(function($oneEntry){
    $oneEntry['historic_data_group_id'] = 1;
    return $oneEntry;
}, $csv->content);
```

but cycling through the array seems more readable

```
foreach ($csv->content as &$content) {
    $content['historic_data_group_id'] = 1;
}
// unset($content);
```

Answer (score 0):

your model `HistoricData` already has this column? if not yet create migration to add this column with default 1. In new inserts its work auto (no need change $csv)

Comment: I should have clarified that I only want it equal to one on this particular insert. It will be a different value for a different csv, so it shouldn't have w default value.